# Operating system updates using AppCenter stuck

Tags: updates, appcenter

[image: Update progress reached this point after 30 minutes then stuck for the past ~8 hours]

I was trying to update the operating system through AppCenter.  It has been running for over 8 hours (still running).  Would like to know:

1. Is this normal?
2. Is it safe to stop the update?
3. Any way to stop this safely...

For now I have made a backup of my files.  I have experienced something similar in the past and tried to solve it by force shut down the system.  A bad move that resulted in a complete OS reinstall..

Please let me know if any more information is needed.  Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a fresh install, I always log in and restart before running any updates because I've had this issue as well. Logging out of your session might fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this install has been my daily driver for a few months now.  Would hate to re-setup everything again.

Comment: Tried logging out and it worked!